# C# Testing Lines of Code Covered Using Ruby/Cucumber Testing Framework

Tags: c#, ruby, cucumber, code-coverage, bdd

I have recently taken over a team that uses Ruby with Cucumber for BDD style integration and UI tests.  My unit's Chief Executive Officer (who does not have a software background) wants to see KPIs for testing coverage... specifically lines of code covered, etc. that you would normally see when using a unit testing framework such as NUnit or XUnit.  With BDD, you generally don't have these types of metrics... or am I wrong?  If there is someone out there that knows how to get lines of code covered metrics from a BDD style framework like Ruby/Cucumber, your thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your CEO is right. BDD and Cucumber are certainly compatible with measuring code coverage.

If I understand correctly you're using Ruby Cucumber to test a C# application. Set up the test instance of the C# application to collect coverage as it runs, run your Cucumber tests, stop the application, and generate a coverage report. Unfortunately I don't know C#, so I can't give details.

BDD is not only acceptance testing (Cucumber); BDD uses acceptance tests to drive important scenarios and unit tests to drive details. (If the team you've taken over uses only Cucumber for testing, they probably have too many Cucumber scenarios and their test suite takes a long time to run.) Assuming you do have both acceptance and unit tests, you'll want to merge coverage from both types of tests and report total coverage. The coverage achieved by the acceptance test suite or the unit test suite alone is much less important than the coverage achieved by the two suites together.